# Formatting regular expression output (for Keyboard maestro).

Tags: regex, keyboard-maestro

I have a keyboard macro tool (keyboard maestro) that returns current date in %NumberDate% variable; it contains a string "3/31/15" for March 31, 2015.

The tool supports regular expression, so using the regular expression, I need to transform this value into formatted string of `[yyyy/MM/dd]` format; in this example [2015/03/31].

The expression that I used to extract the information is `(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)`, however, `[20$3/$1/$2]` makes `[2015/3/31]` not `[2015/03/31]`. Is there any way to check if $1 or $2 is one digit to insert 0 automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I could use `ICUDateTimeFor` to get and replace the date format.

```
%ICUDateTimeFor%NOW()+20%[yyyy/MM/dd]%
```

Comment: I never knew about `ICUDateTimeFor`, and think your solution is better than what I had come up with. Mine involved adding `Execute Shell Script` between tasks 1 and 2 in your question and using sed: `echo $KMVAR_date | sed 's/^[0-9]\//0&/' | sed 's/\.*\/\([0-9]\)\/(./\/0\1\//'`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the standard ICUDateTime, you don't need the ICUDateTimeFor.

[image]